# AutoHotKey: shift rbutton Control C trouble

Tags: autohotkey

I would like to remap <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>RButton</kbd> to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>LButton</kbd> on the mouse. Then, at the release of <kbd>RButton</kbd>, send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in order to copy my highlighted selection.

So far, the best I have come up with is this:

```
+rbutton::
+lbutton
keywait rbutton
send {control c}
return
```

Unfortunately, it does not perform the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> command:

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think this would be more appropriate on Superuser that on SO.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to copy text from the current cursor location up to the mouse location when you press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>RButton</kbd>, then use this:

```
+RButton::
    ClipBoard = ; Clear the ClipBoard
    Send, +{lbutton} ; Send the [Shift]+[LButton]
    KeyWait, RButton ; Wait for RButton to be released
    Send, ^c ; Send [Ctrl]+c to copy the selected text to the ClipBoard
    Sleep, 50 ; ClipWait is not reliable and you need a little time for [Ctrl]+c to copy to the clipBoard.
    TrayTip, ClipBoard, %ClipBoard%, 1 ; Show the ClipBoard results
Return
```